# Why does instantiating a set with braces preserve a string within it while instantiating with the set function splits the string?

Tags: python, set

Just the question above.

Why is

```
>>> x = {'foo'}
>>> print(x)
{'foo'}
```

But

```
>>> x = set('foo')
>>> print(x)
{'o', 'f'}
```

Comment: set() treats string as an iterable as it expects an iterable as argument. Where as {} notation treats each elements as individual set element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one is a set literal. This creates a set containing the single element `'foo'`.

The second one is calling the `set()` constructor with `'foo'` as an argument. When `set()` is called with an iterable as an argument, it feeds all elements from that iterable into the set. Since a string is iterable, it gets fed as each element individually. If it makes it easier, you can think of it as "converting" the argument into a set instead of whatever its previous datatype was. This is commonly used to convert lists into sets.

If you want to use the `set()` constructor instead of using a set literal, to construct a single-element set, then you have to put the argument inside another literal: `set(['foo'])`.